# Sorting objects on canvas

Tags: javascript, sorting, canvas, layer

I draw two bottons using a rectangle with text over top.
As you can see I get two different results using the same loop.
The first "button" has the text hidden behind the box.
The second has the text written on top.
Why is this? How does sorting work in canvas?

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="512"
  style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 50px; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
context.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 16);
gameMenu();

function gameMenu(){
var buttons = [ {x: 210, y: 420, w: 80, h: 30, s: "Messages"},
              {x: 210, y: 470, w: 80, h: 30, s: "Pause"} ], i = 0, r;

    while(r = buttons[i++]) {
    context.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(26,26,26)";
    context.fill();

    context.fillStyle = 'White';
    context.font = "16px Tahoma";
    context.fillText(r.s, r.x + 18, r.y + 22);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/oa84Lsxn/1/

Comment: There's no sorting, you'll need to draw the objects in the correct order, from bottom up.

Comment: @Cyclone. Good info, but the questioner has a different problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must begin each new path operation (==each new `.rect`) with `context.beginPath`. Otherwise all previous .rects will be redrawn along with the current .rect.

Your issue is that all previous paths are redrawn along with the new path. This means your first rect is being redrawn along with your new second rect -- causing the first rect's text to be overwritten by the first rect.

Here's a working version your code with `context.beginPath` added.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
context.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 16);
gameMenu();

function gameMenu(){
// x,y changed to fit demo on StackSnipped window
var buttons = [ {x: 40, y: 20, w: 80, h: 30, s: "Messages"},
              {x: 40, y: 70, w: 80, h: 30, s: "Pause"} ], 
              i = 0, r;

    while(r = buttons[i++]) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(26,26,26)";
        context.fill();

        context.fillStyle = 'White';
        context.font = "16px Tahoma";
        context.fillText(r.s, r.x + 18, r.y + 22);
    }

}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D
Great explanation.

Comment: @Lloyd Alternatively use fillRect() instead of rect() + fill(). If markE answered the question feel free to mark it as accepted. That will close the question and give answerer some points for the effort.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure out how to close it. It was the green checkmark :)